# How to just override sourceSets in a different gradle file

Tags: java, gradle

How to just override sourceSets between gradle files without copying over all definitions. I want to define all groovy functions to build Bar Application in build-bar.gradle but just inherit everything from build-bar.gradle and override `just` the sourceSets in build-baz.gradle file. How can we do this?

Bar Application contains this

```
build-bar.gradle
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/foo/BarApplication.java'
        }   
    }   
}
```

Baz Application contains this

```
build-baz.gradle
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            exclude 'com/foo/BazApplication.java'
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: have you considered to create a library?

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: [Sharing Build Logic between Subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html).